# Can't put print statement in generator

Tags: python, generator

What's going on here? Why doesn't the latter work?

```
def foo(arg): print(arg)
for _ in (foo(x) for x in range(10)): pass   # Works
for _ in (print(x) for x in range(10)): pass # Doesn't work
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x? `print` is a statement, and you can't put statements in a generator expression, only other expressions.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work (Py3) - prints `0..9` for me, but this is an *awful* use of a generator and you shouldn't do it. If you are using Py2, then `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: I tested that last line can work on my Python 3.6.6 on Windows 10. What's your error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would work in Python 3.x, but not in Python 2.x because `print` is a statement in Python 2.x and you cannot put a statement in a generator expression.

If you insist you can make it work by converting `print` to a Python 3-compatible function in Python 2.x with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

But even in Python 3.x it is not recommended to put a function that always returns `None` in a generator expression, since a generator is meant to produce values.

Comment: Note: It would work in Python 2 as well if `from __future__ import print_function` was in effect. It would still be terrible to use generator expressions for side-effects like that though.

Comment: Yes, added to the answer.